# Regex masking of words that contain a digit

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to come up with a 'simple' regex to mask bits of text that look like they might contain account numbers.

In plain English:

- any word containing a digit (or a train of such words) should be matched
- leave the last 4 digits intact
- replace all previous part of the matched string with four X's (xxxx)

**So far**

I'm using the following:

```
[\-0-9 ]+(?<m1>[\-0-9]{4})
```

replacing with

```
xxxx${m1}
```

But this misses on the last few samples below

**sample data:**

```
123456789
a123b456
a1234b5678
a1234 b5678
111 22 3333
this is a a1234 b5678 test string
```

**Actual results**

```
xxxx6789
a123b456
a1234b5678
a1234 b5678
xxxx3333
this is a a1234 b5678 test string
```

**Expected results**

```
xxxx6789
xxxxb456
xxxx5678
xxxx5678
xxxx3333
this is a xxxx5678 test string
```

Is such an arrangement possible with a regex replace?

I think I"m going to need some greediness and lookahead functionality, but I have zero experience in those areas.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't see the problem ? What are the wrong results you are getting ?

Comment: @Sniffer I've added the actual results based on his patterns.

Comment: Are your expected results right? `xxxxb456` doesn't look like it should be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that regex is the best way to solve this problem and that's why I am posting this answer. For so complex situations, building the corresponding regex is too difficult and, what is worse, its clarity and adaptability is much lower than a longer-code approach.

The code below these lines delivers the exact functionality you are after, it is clear enough and can be easily extended.

```
string input = "this is a a1234 b5678 test string";
string output = "";
string[] temp = input.Trim().Split(' ');
bool previousNum = false;
string tempOutput = "";
foreach (string word in temp)
{
    if (word.ToCharArray().Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).Count() > 0)
    {
        previousNum = true;
        tempOutput = tempOutput + word;
    }
    else
    {
        if (previousNum)
        {
            if (tempOutput.Length >= 4) tempOutput = "xxxx" + tempOutput.Substring(tempOutput.Length - 4, 4);
            output = output + " " + tempOutput;
            previousNum = false;
        }
        output = output + " " + word;
    }
}
if (previousNum)
{
    if (tempOutput.Length >= 4) tempOutput = "xxxx" + tempOutput.Substring(tempOutput.Length - 4, 4);
    output = output + " " + tempOutput;
    previousNum = false;
}
```

Comment: One quick comment, where you say `if (!previousNum) previousNum = true;` you can reduce complexity by just saying `previousNum = true;` and removing the if statement.  It will reduce the cyclomatic complexity by 1 for that statement

Comment: @joe_coolish you are completely and absolutely right. I wrote the code quickly.

Comment: other than that, +1 for unwrapping the regex!

Comment: I agree that straight regex is not the best way... But such was my quest

Comment: @BrianAdkins I am happy to read that we both agree on that. You can continue trying to get the regex-based approach (because you are instructed to do so or because it is a personal challenge or because of whatever reason) and, in case of not finding anything delivering an accurate enough solution, you could just rely on this code.

Answer (score 3):

This works for your example:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(
    input,
    @"(?<!\b\w*\d\w*)(?<m1>\s?\b\w*\d\w*)+",
    m => "xxxx" + m.Value.Substring(Math.Max(0, m.Value.Length - 4)));
```

If you have a value like `111 2233 33`, it will print `xxxx3 33`. If you want this to be free from spaces, you could turn the lambda into a multi-line statement that removes whitespace from the value.

To explain the regex pattern a bit, it's got a negative lookbehind, so it makes sure that the word behind it does not have a digit in it (with optional word characters around the digit). Then it's got the `m1` portion, which looks for words with digits in them. The last four characters of this are grabbed via some C# code after the regex pattern resolves the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
.*(?<m1>[\d]{4})(?<m2>.*)
```

with replacement

```
xxxx${m1}${m2}
```

This produces

```
xxxx6789
xxxx5678
xxxx5678
xxxx3333
xxxx5678 test string
```

You are not going to get 'a123b456' to match ... until 'b' becomes a number. ;-)

Comment: This will replace the "This is a" in the last example

Comment: At the time I wrote the answer his example also removed that.  Since then the requirements changed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my really quick attempt:

```
(\s|^)([a-z]*\d+[a-z,0-9]+\s)+
```

This will select all of those test cases.  Now as for C# code, you'll need to check each match to see if there is a space at the beginning or end of the match sequence (e.g., the last example will have the space before and after selected)

here is the C# code to do the replace:

```
var redacted = Regex.Replace(record, @"(\s|^)([a-z]*\d+[a-z,0-9]+\s)+",
    match => "xxxx" /*new String("x",match.Value.Length - 4)*/ + 
    match.Value.Substring(Math.Max(0, match.Value.Length - 4)));
```